# Global JS function Not Available Wordpress - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

My global function is not available because "$ is not a function".

But I do have jquery as a dependency to my own js file:

```
wp_enqueue_script('common-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/common.js', array('jquery'), CHILD_THEME_ASTRA_CHILD_VERSION, true);
```

[image]

Why I cannot use jQuery outside of document ready?

Answer (score 0):

try out the below code might help you in achieving the result.

```
jQuery(function($){
    
     function closeOverlay(){
        // Logic Here
     }
     function openOverlay(){
       // Logic Here 
     }

});
```

Comment: `jQuery(function(){` is the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function(){`

Answer (score 0):

This will create an anonymous function that will be called immediately ( `Immediately Invoked Function Expression` or `IIFE` ) with the `$` param and the supplied value for the `$` is `jQuery`. This way, you make sure that all the code inside this can use `$` without polluting the global space

```
(function ($) {
    function whatever(){
        $('.selector').slideUp();
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
       // some code here
    });
})(jQuery);
```